# How do I profile Lambda function performance?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, lambda

In Visual Studio 2012, my program spends about 35% of its time inside a lambda function, but when I try to profile my code (ANALYZE -> Start Performance Analysis) it just says that it's spending 35% of execution time inside the "populate" functor (the lambda object).

The body of the lambda object cannot be displayed and I cannot see what it is inside the lambda that is taking up all that time.

I am deliberately not posting the lambda itself because I want to know *how* to find this information within the Visual Studio program, not the problems in my code (my code is of course always perfect, and this is merely an academic exercise).

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

Comment: Copy the code from the lambda into a method, and call that method instead?..

Comment: I was just thinking something like dasblinkenlight's suggestion - a function/method with a name is probably more "available" to debug/profiling tools.

Comment: Yeah that would work, but it's not ideal because a function call is slower than the evaluation of a static lambda - at least on my system according to the profiler - so it's not necessarily an accurate comparison. But if that's the only option I guess I'll have to do that. Cheers.

Comment: Why would it be slower? Surely the compiler generates the same code for both cases - any chance you could give us a small sample of how you find that difference [ideally using some simple testcase].

Answer (score 0):

The details are being aggregated.  Try turning off Tools/Options/Performance Tools/General/Just My Code/Enable Just My Code for profile reports (sampling).